# How to clean Stack Trace in Deno?

Tags: deno

I'm using custom `raise` function to throw errors and the first line in stack trace contains the `raise` function itself.

I would like to remove the first line, but it doesn't work in Deno, it still prints it, example:

```
window.raise = function (msg) {
  var e, lines;
  e = new Error(msg);
  // Removing raise from stack trace
  lines = e.stack.split("\n");
  lines.splice(1, 1);
  e.stack = lines.join("\n");
  throw e;
}
raise('test')
```

It still prints the first line:

```
> deno run ./play.js
error: Uncaught Error: test
  e = new Error(msg);
      ^
    at window.raise (file:///play.js:3:7)
    at file:///play.js:10:1
```

Expected:

```
> deno run ./play.js
error: Uncaught Error: test
  e = new Error(msg);
      ^
    at file:///play.js:10:1
```

Comment: Typically the solution to this is for your raise function to not be the function that throws the error, but just act as a factory function. Then whatever needs this custom error can call `throw raise(..)`

Comment: All assuming there's a point to `raise()` because right now it doesn't seem to be doing anything more than `new Error()` already does. Of course you could also subclass Error if that suits your needs.

Comment: It seems like this is [a problem encountered while to trying to solve the actual problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why try to modify the stack trace? What problem do you think that addresses? Like @Evert [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046267/how-to-clean-stack-trace-in-deno#comment135823625_77046267), there's likely another common/conventional way to approach it.